# Structure of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra of $\mathcal{S}*\mathcal{L}$ in Hartshorne II.7.9

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In lemma II.7.9 Hartshorne define a graded $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra $\mathcal{S}'$ from a graded algebra $\mathcal{S}$ and an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ by set up for each $d\geqslant0$,
$$ \mathcal{S}'_d=\mathcal{S}_d\otimes\mathcal{L}^d$$
I can't see why such a definition define an $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra. I can see that it is a graded $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, I guess that we can give it a structure of non-commutative $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra but there is clearly a problem of commutativity coming from tensor products. I see that locally, on small enough open set $U$ we have ${\mathcal{S}'}_{|U}\simeq\mathcal{S}_{|U}$ because $\mathcal{L}_{|U}\simeq\mathcal{O}_X$ but it's only local.

Comment: You just twist the tensor product around to get commutativity: $(\mathcal{S}_d\otimes\mathcal{L}^d)\otimes(\mathcal{S}_e\otimes\mathcal{L}^e)\xrightarrow{\cong}(\mathcal{S}_d\otimes\mathcal{S}_e)\otimes(\mathcal{L}^d\otimes\mathcal{L}^e)\xrightarrow{\operatorname{m}_{\mathcal{S}}\otimes 1}\mathcal{S}_{d+e}\otimes\mathcal{L}^{d+e}$ (since $\mathcal{S}$ is commutative).

Comment: But in $\mathcal{L}^{d+e}$ we don not have commutativity for sections: I mean that for example $fg\otimes x_1\otimes x_2\neq fg\otimes x_2\otimes x_1$??

Comment: $\mathcal{L}^{d+e}$ is an invertible sheaf, so $x_1\otimes x_2=x_2\otimes x_1$ on affines, hence it is commutative (just patch).

Comment: But for all $U$, $\mathcal{S}'(U)$ should be a ring, not only for affine open subset??

Comment: You have the ring structure on the affines commutes with restrictions, so they patch.

Comment: Ok I convince myself for the ring structure on affine U: $x_1\otimes x_2=x_2\otimes x_1$ because it is locally true ie for all $V\subseteq U$ enough small $(x_1\otimes x_2)_{|V}=(x_2\otimes x_1) _{|V}$.